# ARM NEON, set lane from indexed array?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, arm, neon

I have some source code here that does linear interpolation, but needs 4 values each that are given by indices into an array:

```
float32x4_t fraction = ... (4 floats in range 0<f<1)

uint32x4_t idxA = ... (4 indices into float array)
uint32x4_t idxB = ... (4 indices into float array)

uint32_t indicesA[4];   vst1q_u32( indicesA, idxA );
uint32_t indicesB[4];   vst1q_u32( indicesB, idxB );

float32x4_t arrValuesA, arrValuesB;

arrValuesA = vsetq_lane_f32(_arr[indicesA[0]], arrValuesA, 0 );
arrValuesA = vsetq_lane_f32(_arr[indicesA[1]], arrValuesA, 1 );
arrValuesA = vsetq_lane_f32(_arr[indicesA[2]], arrValuesA, 2 );
arrValuesA = vsetq_lane_f32(_arr[indicesA[3]], arrValuesA, 3 );

arrValuesB = vsetq_lane_f32(_arr[indicesB[0]], arrValuesB, 0 );
arrValuesB = vsetq_lane_f32(_arr[indicesB[1]], arrValuesB, 1 );
arrValuesB = vsetq_lane_f32(_arr[indicesB[2]], arrValuesB, 2 );
arrValuesB = vsetq_lane_f32(_arr[indicesB[3]], arrValuesB, 3 );

float32x4_t diff = vsubq_f32(arrValuesA, arrValuesB);

float32x4_t result = vmlaq_f32( arrValuesA, diff, fraction );
```

The "problem" is, that it's not fast enough, It takes 4 single float instruction and 4 array lookups to feed each lane. If I use normal C code the speed is the same.

Anyone knows how to optimize this further? I didn't find any instructions to read values by array lookup directly.

Comment: If these are just randomly located floats then NEON is probably not going to be useful.  What you want is to be able to load vectors (i.e. contiguous in memory) and perform the same operation on all lanes.  Maybe if you give your C code and some more information about what exactly you're trying to do someone will have more ideas.

Comment: The code is used for generating wavetables out of sine waves of different frequencies. _arr is the sine table and "fraction" represents the current angle of the sine wave where the angle at index 0 is x, the angle at index 1 is x*2, index 2 is x*3 and so on... of course wrapped, into the array range length. The index generation works fine using neon instructions, the only thing left is accessing the values of the sine table.

Comment: A much more efficient implementation would use integer fractional values and something like the vqdmulh instruction to normalize the values in a single instruction. (e.g. 16-bit fraction 1/2 == 0x4000 (because it's doubled by the instruction).